# Property [posts] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel

Hope you're all having a good day. I'm working on a blogs page and reached a part where I want to display the certain blogs a user has posted. I added relations to the Post model and User model but i can't seem to get the specific posts of the logged in user and it gives me the error above in the title. Here are my models and Profile controller.
[The users schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjDyy.png)[The posts schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHFvJ.png)
Post model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
   
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');

    }
}
```

Posts function in User model

```
  public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);

    }
```

The ProfileController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Reviews;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $user_id=auth()->user()->id;


        $user = User::where('id', $user_id)->get();
        $posts= $user->posts;//Gets all details of the user with id 123

        return view('profile')->with(['users' => $user ],['posts', $posts]);
    }
}
```

Comment: get() is multidimensional data, you cant get relationship without loop, maybe you mean first()

Comment: side note: `'posts'` wont make it to the view the way you are trying to pass it ... `with(['user' => ..., 'posts' => ...])` would do it

Comment: first() actually doesn't work

Comment: please share your table schemes, how your user and post table look like

Comment: what to you get if you use `$user = auth()->user(); $post = $user->posts;`?

Comment: @lagbox yep didn't see it. Im so sorry. Thought you meant the => operands

Comment: @Brian no worries ... good luck with the project :-)

Comment: @lagbox Thanks! Didn't work though. Foreach error now. I'm tired. I'll retrace my steps to see if i did anything wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = User::where('id', $user_id)->get(); // return a collection so it is multiple items and would have to be accessed as so
```

This should be

```
$user = User::where('id', $user_id)->first();
```

Or rather

```
$user = User::find($user_id);
```

But better

```
$user = auth()->user()
```

Be mindful that you are doing some unnecessary work, `auth()->user()` is the user instance there is no need to use that to then get it from the database. As it stands you would have access to the User in the blade template for `profile` using `Auth::user()` So there may be no reason just yet to even do any database queries in the controller. This may change as you build out the page of course

Comment: Oh yes makes sense! No need to fetch the user instance all over again. Since everything is already fetched from the auth instance ,right? That's what I'm understanding from that

Comment: So i just need to initialize `$user = auth()->user() ` and fetch the posts data using that

Comment: i tried `$user=auth()->user();` then `$post= $user->posts;` still an error. Doesn't even fetch the user details

Comment: I cant imagine the error your now getting is `Property [posts] does not exist on this collection instance` so maybe its  a new error message?

Comment: Yes its a completely new one. undefined $posts variable when i try to output. the page loads  without the foreach loop outputting though no more Property error. But with the foreach loop the variable error occurs

Comment: But In the tutorial i was following the guy did everything the same way on the posts part and it worked so right now i have no idea what i did wrong.